# How to bulk delete content of a given type?

Tags: nodes

I need to delete all content of a content type. I'm allowed to select up to 50 node per deletion process. My problem is that I have 900 nodes then I need to repeat this 18 times.

Anyway to select all nodes to mass delete them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [Views Bulk Operation](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module. This allows you to create list for exactly this purpose and gives you some other interesting functions.

Comment: The OP is not using views i think.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any modules, 
Try adding a custom page and put this code

```
<?php
$node_type = 'MYTYPE';
  //fetch the nodes we want to delete
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type='%s'",$node_type);
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
    set_time_limit(20);
    node_delete($row->nid);
    $deleted_count+=1;
  }
  //simple debug message so we can see what had been deleted.
  drupal_set_message("$deleted_count nodes have been deleted");
?>
```

Edit Accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Devel generate module, then use Drush, one command does it all, easy.

```
drush genc 0 --kill --types='your_content_type_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 
[Delete all](https://drupal.org/project/delete_all) module, navigate to 'admin/content/delete_content' and you will be presented with a form for deletion of content belonging to certain content types. 
I tend to agree that this solution is more suitable for this use-case compared to the accepted answer (which is also a viable solution).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform bulk operations, then I would recommend [Administration Views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.

> **Features**
>
> - Filter all administrative views via AJAX.
> - Perform any kind of bulk/mass operations on items in administrative    views.
> - Filter content by title, node type, author, published status, and/or    vocabulary.
> - Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
> - Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.