# Deleting nodes did not remove the node-related menus

Tags: nodes

Is there a "safe" way to delete all the existing content/pages/nodes from a Drupal 7 site, and delete corresponding menu entries?  When I deleted the nodes using the admin UI, my menu entries didn't get deleted?  What can cause this?

[image: snapshot 1]

[image: snapshot 2]

Comment: are you facing any issue if you delete it directly form the drupal admin?

Comment: Yes, the content from all the other menus is gone, but in the Administration it is still showing up (only when I go to structure/menus/list links though).

What is the best practice when it comes to bulk deleting the existing nodes/content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all nodes of a given content type](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/537/delete-all-nodes-of-a-given-content-type)

Comment: Thanks for that. I only had about 20 nodes all up, so deleting them via the interface wasn't an issue...

Comment: @user12804, then, your question should be updated what is your actual problem is. As your question was to delete all nodes, my answer below is the direct answer to it.

Comment: @user12804, your question should be just like "deleting nodes did not remove the node-related menus". Am I right?

Comment: You are right. :(
I've changed it now. Sorry, my common sense isn't with me today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Q/A may be helpful for you:
[Delete all nodes of a given content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/537/delete-all-nodes-of-a-given-content-type)
[How to bulk delete content of a given type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/how-to-bulk-delete-content-of-a-given-type)
According to the first Q/A, the [Delete all](http://drupal.org/project/delete_all) module is worth to try.

You could also try [mass delete node](http://stream.zerolab.org/post/917260717/mass-delete-nodes-in-drupal). The function [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) is safe to call. It has a call to [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) which deletes all related components of a node, such as entities, files, revisions, history, etc.

**[UPDATE]**
If you already deleted your nodes, but node-related menus are still there, you could also try out [menu_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) to rebuild your navigation menus. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912110/1179841). You could also add `menu_rebuild()` at the end of the script of [mass delete node](http://stream.zerolab.org/post/917260717/mass-delete-nodes-in-drupal) I mentioned above.

OR

If you know menu IDs, you can remove each of them using [menu_link_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_delete/7).

Comment: Thanks for that. I only had about 20 nodes all up, so deleting them via the interface wasn't an issue... The issue is that deleting them didn't remove them from the Navigation menu :S

Comment: Have you cleared caches?

Comment: What is your navigation menu structure? Can you show us a screen shot? I believe that if a node has been deleted, the menu path point to the node is not valid anymore. They should be disappeared from the menu, or we can delete the menus manually by ourselves writing a script, just like [mass delete node](http://stream.zerolab.org/post/917260717/mass-delete-nodes-in-drupal) I mentioned.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/screenshot20130128at354.png/

Comment: http://imageshack.us/a/img405/8272/screenshot20130128at353.png

Comment: @user12804, pls check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!!!

Will the following code delete ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING:
<?php
  // Bootstrap
  // Change chdir to the full path of your Drupal root
  chdir('/home/myusername/public_html/');
  define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
  require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

  // Rebuild
  menu_rebuild();
?>

Comment: You could also add menu_rebuild() at the end of the script of [mass delete node](http://stream.zerolab.org/post/917260717/mass-delete-nodes-in-drupal) I mentioned above. This is an alternative way of deleting nodes without using interface.

Comment: Oooops. Just realised that a lot of those are actually content types. Perhaps I should delete them from the content type window instead...

Comment: Bizzare... Removed all the content types except for "Basic page", yet they are still being listed in the Navigation menu.

Comment: just menu_rebuild() or flush all caches.

Comment: I thought that un-ticking the checkbox under the Enable column might get rid of the links, but they are still there. Uggh

Comment: Right, you are just disabling the menus!